How to construct a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of $\mathscr{A}$-measurable simple functions such that $|g_n(x)|=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)f(x)=|f(x)|$?
I am in the middle of proving a result. It would be unnecessary to type the whole thing out. I just want to ask one step where I got stuck on.
So let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that $f$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{C})$. How can I construct a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of $\mathscr{A}$-measurable simple functions for which the relations $|g_n(x)|=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)f(x) = |f(x)|$ hold at each $x$ in $X$?
Thank you very much for any help!

First, let $g(x)$ be defined by,
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)}, & \text{if } f(x) \neq 0\\
1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then $|g(x)| = 1$ and $g(x)f(x) = |f(x)|$ for all $x$.
We now construct $g_n$ so that they approximate $g$. For any $z \in U(1)$, we let $\arg(z)$ be the unique $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ s.t. $z = e^{i\theta}$. Now define,
$$g_n(x) = e^{\frac{2\pi mi}{n}}, \; \text{when } \frac{2\pi m}{n} \leq \arg(g(x)) < \frac{2\pi (m + 1)}{n}, \; \text{for } 0 \leq m < n$$
One easily observes that $|g_n(x)| = 1$ and $g_n(x) \to g(x)$ (so $g_n(x)f(x) \to |f(x)|$) for all $x$. It is also easy to see that $g_n$ is measurable, and, as it takes at most $n$ values, it is indeed a simple function.
